# How to transform keras.tensor to numpy and turn it back then

Tags: python, numpy, keras

When I use keras to build my model,I meet a problem as follows:
I want to use the function called cv2.Canny(),but it needs a numpy as its input.So I want to transform my keras.tensor to nd.array,and then transform it back to keras.tensor to continue the model's building.

The question is :

1. how can i transform the keras.tensor to nd.array?
2. how can i transform the nd.array back to the keras.tensor?

I have tried lots of solutions but nothing works, I really don't know how to do.
And here I list my solution.

As for question 1:

1. eval(session=tf.Session())
2. tf.Session.run()
3. K.eval()

I think the solution 3 is correct for my keras model, but I am not sure
As for question 2:

1. some tf function doesn't work
2. I use Input(tensor=K.variable(numpy variable)),

it works!but the last step, I meet a bug called "RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor..."

Comment: post some code please

Comment: @makis
```
z = np.zeros((3,32,32,1))
inp = Input(tensor=K.variable(z))
nu = K.eval(inp)
x = Input(tensor=K.variable(nu))

model = Model(inp,x)
```